# Running a JavaScript function differently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text input like this and it will perform a search on every key input by user. Since the search function takes bit of time to execute user input is stuck until it finishes the execution.

```
  <input type="text" id="suggestion" onkeyup="search();"/>
```

Can we let this search function execute and let the user type in the text field. Something like letting the search run in background.

**ps**. I don't want to use a delaying function to wait until user finishes and call search()

Comment: Try Debouncing: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Where are you outputting your result?

Comment: I'm searching about 3000 rows to find some text details. And if there's anything matching to my search criteria a simple UI change will be done. That's the idea.

Comment: @Tim Ackroyd that answer is not what I'm looking for. That's what I meant by ps.  guess. :)  Btw thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is running on a single thread - therefore, when the search function is running, it also blocks the UI from rendering and responding to you. You should avoid as much as possible doing operations on the browser that last more than 16ms, you can read more about the reasons [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/rendering/).

Anyway, currently there are 2 primary solutions for this:

- Move it to the server-side. What's the search logic that you run in JavaScript? should it really run on the client-side and not on the server-side?
- Execute it on another thread. Are you familiar with WebWorkers? It's a more advanced topic, but generally it allow you to execute code on another thread. It's quite new and [not fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) yet in today's browsers, but you should at least be familiar with it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of letting it run every time set a global switch using

```
window.somevar = true;
```

Then check if that variable is set before searching again. Once the initial search is complete then show your results and unset the global variable

```
delete window.somevar;
```

That way the function "runs" each keystroke, but doesn't lock up the input.